# Can I have more than 1 <appender> stanza for the same log file in a jboss-log4j.xml?

Tags: jboss, log4j, logging

I'm working with my first jboss application server and am having some issues with the log files.  Currently there is a bug in the software that is constantly streaming errors in the log file, each day I get a 708MB log file, and this quickly fills the HD space of the server.

In the jboss-log4j.xml I have 2 `<appender>` stanza's, one that rolls the log file each day, and a second that limits the log files to 10MB and keeps only the last 20 logs.  Currently only the first stanza seems to be working.  Based on this I think I can only have 1 `<appender>` stanza and need to merge these two....

Am I on the right track?  If so can you provide some tips how I can merge these two together?

```
<!-- A time/date based rolling appender -->
<appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
   <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
   <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
   <param name="Append" value="false"/>

   <!-- Rollover at midnight each day -->
   <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>

   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>

   </layout>
</appender>

<!-- A size based file rolling appender -->
<appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
 <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
 <param name="Append" value="false"/>
 <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20"/>

 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
 </layout>     
</appender>
```

Comment: Please provide the full set of appenders that you have

Comment: @Heiko Rupp - Im trying to post it, but SO is hiding a lot of the XML for some reason....  If you have edit capability take a look at the post and you'll see more XML in there than what is showing

Comment: You need to use the { } function on top of the editor to properly escape that. Then it should be ok

Comment: @Heiko Rupp - It was a typo, some lines where only had 3 preceding spaces.  Its all shown now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have two `<appender>` nodes writing to the same `name='FILE'`.
It is also not possible to merge these two `<appender>`'s into one stanza.

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one appender - default is to have a file appender for the log file and another for the console.

It looks like in your code you are writing to the same file in both cases, which probably
does not make much sense and also does not sound like what you want from the description you gave.

Comment: But can I have 2 for the FILE?

Comment: Yes Im trying to write to the same file with both `<appender>` nodes.  Is this possible?  I'm extremely new to jboss, like I mentioned.  Can I merge these two `<appender>`'s together?  Here is what I would like to happen: 1) a new log file created daily at midnight. 2) Log files should not exceed 10MB  3) Retain only the last 20 log files on disk.

Comment: Even if the naming suggests, it looks like the DailyRollingFileAppender does not extend the RollingFileAppender and does not inherit the size and index attributes. So I think this will not work as desired. This is a limitation of the underlying log4j library.